# Set state in parent component so that child components can access state

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set up state for a portion of my web game that allows players to upload photos of their monsters.

I have a parent component called `<MonsterContainer>`.  It contains two child components: `<MonsterPortraitUpload>` and `<MonsterViewer>`

I am setting state in `<MonsterContainer>`

`<MonsterPortraitUpload>` Will allow users to upload photos and it will add to the MonsterPortraits array in the state.

`<MonsterViewer>` Will show all the photos of the monster in the array.

How can I ensure that my two child components have access to this state?

Here is what I have now:

```
class MonsterContainer extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        MonsterPortraits: []
    };
}

render() {
    const { monsterId } = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <MonsterPortraitUpload monsterId={monsterId}/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <MonsterViewer monsterId={monsterId}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Right now I am trying to write the state to the console in `<MonsterViewer>` but I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'MonsterPortraits' of null

Comment: You need to pass down `MonsterPortraits` as props to `MonsterPortraitUpload` and `MonsterViewer`, like you have done with `monsterId`: `<MonsterViewer monsterId={monsterId} MonsterPortraits={this.state.MonsterPortraits} />`

Comment: You should only pass down information to child components that they actually need. So extract the required information from the monster (e.g. name, image, powers) and pass that down instead of just an id.

Comment: @Tholle Works but passing all monsters to a component that should display a single monster seems odd to me. Better have a container component that owns the list of monsters and only pass single monsters down.

Comment: @trixn Yes, I was just answering why `MonsterPortraits` was not available in `MonsterViewer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Child components *don't* have access to parent state; data flows one way: down.

If a child component needs access to parent state that state should be passed as a property.

If that is insufficient for your needs (e.g., a deeply-nested hierarchy where children need to update state at a much higher level) then you'll probably want a different state management system, e.g., Redux/etc.

In your case, as presented, passing down the array of portraits to `<MonsterView />` would seem sufficient, and `<MonsterPortraitUpload />` would take a function prop that adds to the container's state (e.g., add a portrait).

This is a fundamental concept in React and similar: dumb components, smart containers. Dump components take data and functions, containers manage state. This breaks down in deep hierarchies because you end up having to pass properties down multiple levels.

That *may* be address via React Contexts, or injecting properties into cloned children, etc., but whether or not those are good solutions depends on your architecture. In general, a different form of state management can make problems like this go away by introducing a thin layer of complexity.

To modify the container's state you pass a hander; very off-the-cuff:

```js
class MonsterContainer extends Component {
  // Etc.

  addPortrait(someData) {
    this.setState([ ...this.state.MonsterPortraits, someData ]);
  }

  render() {
    // Etc.
    <MonsterPortraitUpload addHandler={this.addPortrait} />
```

In `<MonsterPortraitUpload />` you'd create the data however (e.g., a form) and then on a user action (e.g., a button press) you call the container's handler function passing whatever data:

```
class MonsterPortraitUpload extends Component {
  addPortait() {
    // Marshall the data however, then
    this.props.addPortrait(newData);
  }
  // Etc.
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is just a simple game.  So I see how to pass data from the state to the child components, but in MonsterPortraitUpload, I need to upload new photos to the state, how would this be done?  Thanks

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Updated.

Answer (score 1):

An error that you show, definitely not from attached code.
If you need to pass state down use this

```
class MonsterContainer extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
          MonsterPortraits: []
      };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <MonsterPortraitUpload monsterPortraits={this.state.MonsterPortraits}/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <MonsterViewer monsterPortraits={this.state.MonsterPortraits}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So in `MonsterPortraitUpload` component you may use `this.props.monsterPortraits`